# Using 64-Bit SPSS Libraries in C#

Tags: c#, 64-bit, spss

I'm trying to create an `.sav` file programmatically without having to use SPSS automation (the SPSS.BackendAPI library) in order to free up more SPSS licenses. I found [this library](http://spss.codeplex.com/) at CodePlex that uses the 32-bit I/O module without requiring a license, which is good.

The problem is that I need to build the application as x64 in order to gain access to the extra addressable memory in my own application. Thus, I need to use the 64-bit libraries as well. Has anyone had luck using the 64-bit libraries in managed code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use that library from CodePlex, but you'll have to modify it a bit to work with the spssio64.dll that's included with the I/O Module. In the `SpssThinWrapper.cs` file, you'll need to change the DLL that's being imported. You'll also have to change some of the entry points. To get the names of the entry points in the 64-bit DLL, you'll want to run `dumpbin /exports spssio64.dll`. If you do this you'll see that the the 64-bit and 32-bit entry points are basically the same, except that some of the 32-bit ones have an @ sign and a number after them, whereas none of the 64-bit entry points do. Do change all of those along with the DLL in the DllImport attribute. For example:

```
[DllImport("spssio32.dll", EntryPoint="spssCloseAppend@4", CharSet=CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError=true, ExactSpelling=true)]
public static extern ReturnCode spssCloseAppend(int handle);
```

becomes

```
[DllImport("spssio64.dll", EntryPoint = "spssCloseAppend", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
public static extern ReturnCode spssCloseAppend(int handle);
```

and so on.

After doing this you'll want to make sure you're using the correct DLLs. Copy the spssio64.dll, icudt32.dll, icuin32.dll, and icuuc32.dll from the win64 folder of the I/O Module into the Resources folder from the SPSS .NET library from CodePlex. This will overwrite the existing 32-bit dlls, so if you need both 32-bit and 64-bit you'll have to do something different, but it sounds like you just need 64-bit, so this should work.

As an example of how easy it is to create an `.sav` with this library:

```
using (SpssDataDocument spssDoc = SpssDataDocument.Create("test.sav")) { 
    SpssVariable v = new SpssNumericVariable(); 
    v.Name = "gender"; 
    v.Label = "What is your gender?"; 
    v.ValueLabels.Add(1, "Male"); 
    v.ValueLabels.Add(2, "Female"); 
    doc.Variables.Add(v); 
    doc.CommitDictionary();
    SpssCase c = doc.Cases.New();
    c["gender"] = 1;
    c.Commit();
}
```

The library handles all of the spss* calls for you, and makes sure they're in the right order and everything.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just use the SPSS Statistics i/o dll available via the SPSS Community site (www.ibm.com/developerworks/spssdevcentral)?  It is free and comes in 32 and 64 bit versions for all the supported SPSS platforms.  It does not require an SPSS license.

Comment: AFAIK, the library I linked to in the question actually wraps the I/O DLL you refer to. The wrapper just gives a more object-oriented view of things.

Comment: That's exactly right. It provides a pretty "thick" wrapper around those DLLs. I've edited my answer to include an example.