# How to connect SPSS and ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, spss

May I connect SPSS and ASP.Net. I want to create forecast table in ASP.Net for using SPSS. How can I do this?

Comment: is this option available to SPSS, you speak for a program , what are the options that this program gives to interact with him via functions and with out windows environment ? Read the manual of the SPSS, and if there exist a connection via c,c++,c# then this is what you like to focus

Answer (score 0):

merthsoft's answer on the following stackoverflow posting provides a good starting point for getting spss up and running.

[Using 64-Bit SPSS Libraries in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598968/using-64-bit-spss-libraries-in-c-sharp)

Basically copy the dlls provided by SPSS into your system32 folder on your server and wrap up the spssio64.dll's calls so you can call it from your code. If you are using C#, you can use the DLLImport attribute.

The hangups I personally had were including all of the appropriate dlls like... spssio64.dll, icudt32.dll, icuin32.dll and icuuc32.dll

When exporting your data, all columns need to be unique.

I hope by now you got it working, but for those who come across this in the future this may help.